# Can I replace my 4U server PSU with a desktop PSU?

Tags: power-supply, hp-proliant

I have an [HP ML10 v2](http://www8.hp.com/uk/en/products/proliant-servers/product-detail.html?oid=7796450). It uses a [Delta DPS-350AB-20 A](http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/175291/DELTA/DPS-350AB-2.html) 350w mATX PSU. I use this server at home, and the PSU is noisy, so I'm looking to replace it with a [Be Quiet! SP10 CM 500w](http://www.ebuyer.com/666221-be-quiet-straight-power-10-cm-power-supply-500-watts-80-plus-bn234), which is quieter, more efficient and more powerful (I'll eventually be making significant upgrades and I'd like to keep it quiet).

There are two things I can't figure out:

1. I can turn the server `on/off` by sending 'power signals' using `iLO 4`. Does this at all rely on a feature of the PSU, or is it solely the motherboard that manages this?
2. The `SAS cable` by `Amphenol` in the server serves 4 drives, and includes `power`. It has a `10-pin connector` I haven't seen before, that is matched by a connector on the PSU. Is this bespoke, or can I purchase an `adaptor for the new, standard PSU`?

[image: PSU Connector]
[image: PSU Connector Cables]

**UPDATE:**
Following Sami's advice, I went ahead and replaced the PSU as planned. I bought some cable, 4-pin molex connectors and a 10pin connector as this won't be the only cable I make, otherwise I'd go for a molex splitter, cut the ends off and replace it with a 10pin connector. I already had a crimper.

The PSU sits upside down (fan facing upwards) at the top of the chassis, sitting on a shelf. There's just enough clearance above it for me to be comfortable with the fan there. I'm also using a very efficient, high quality power supply.

The PSU I used has a switch on the back. Because the chassis wasn't built to accommodate any other PSU, there is no space for this switch, so the PSU has to sit slightly recessed into the case - I just bought some longer screws and some nylon spacers, and it's perfectly secure.

Remote on/off works fine, that's totally managed by the chipset.

Comment: Would you update your solution with which 4-pin molex to 10pin connector you used? I'd like to do something similar, but can't seem to find those.

(Very detailed photos and question description by the way - helped me identify that I have the same question.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - I made the adaptor myself using end connectors I bought on eBay. The 4pins came from China I think, the 10pins from the UK as the other ones didn't include the metal pins inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually remote startup/shutdown doesn't require any support from the power supply. The remote controller and motherboard will handle all things needed. Even in a "normal" PC the power supply will only supply power when the motherboard so asks and nothing more.

The connector seems to have the normal red, yellow and black wires on it. That would indicate that it can be connected to regular PSU simply by connecting the same color wires to correct positions. Red is +5V, yellow +12V and black of course is the ground.

So based on the power supply being a regular desktop mATX power supply I would say it is highly likely you can switch it with another one and just wire the connector to the appropriate wires in the new PSU.

Comment: Is there a given connector on a standard PSU that would map to this best?

Comment: @StringsOnFire Best way would be to take the regular old style hard/optical drive power connectors, gently remove the wires from the connectors and insert them into the old plastic connector. Not sure if your planned replacement PSU has those still, the picture of cables was not that clear.

Comment: So black, red and yellow will always be the same? In that case, I can get a 10 pin plug and molex plug and wire one to the other as you suggest

Comment: @StringsOnFire Yes, the ATX standard defines them as such so you can take any red, any yellow and any black and use them. Of course it's wise to take a multimeter and check beforehand that nobody has messed things up :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same situation as you, I have an HP Proliant ML10 v2 and also find the PSU fan too noisy. I've checked voltages just to be sure and yes, colors match with standard voltages. This is the $2-$3 hack I'll try in the next days:

- buy 2 of this: "Dual 4 Pin Male Molex IDE to 6 Pin Female PCI-E Y Power Adapter Cable": http://www.ebay.com/itm/New-Dual-4-Pin-Male-Molex-IDE-to-6-Pin-Female-PCI-E-Y-Power-Adapter-Cable-/191381793004

And just follow this nice scheme. Yes, Paintbrush powa! :)

[image]

Comment: Also I'll try changing the rear case fan:

 - Arctic Cooling F9 92mm PWM Fan:
   [link](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Arctic-Cooling-F9-92mm-PWM-Case-Fan-9-2cm-Computer-PC-CPU-Heatsink-Cooler-/111447595227)

Comment: I think you have it backwards - get a 10pin connector with pins on eBay, and a 4 pin molex power splitter. I've updated the question with my solution. Then you don't need to hack apart a connector and it'll clip together properly. I'd be interested to see how you do the case fan - I'm concerned it's pulling some data from a sensor in the fan or something, hence the extra wires

Comment: Well, this is the cheapest solution I've found, less than $3. For the case fan, have a look at this: http://www.silentpcreview.com/article1377-page9.html and this http://homeservershow.com/forums/index.php?/topic/7294-faking-the-fan-signal/page-3#entry93594

Answer (score 1):

As it uses standard ATX voltages and colors, the quickest way to use a new supply would have been to remove the molex connecter from the old supply and put it on the new supply.

Video of how it's done: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y1DPdI-tvoQ

You can use a simple jewelers screwdriver, a paperclip, even a straightened staple. It's not hard at all. There are dedicated tools if you want.

The tangs need to be pushed in a bit then the wire with pin can be slid out.

[image]

[image]

Do this for the 10 pin connector on the old supply, and on two 4 pin connectors on the new supply. Fix the tangs by pulling them out a bit and insert the wires into the 10 pin connector. No need to cut/solder an adapter.

Comment: No embedded youtube videos? Boo superuser.

Comment: Fair point - I didn't do this as, when I upgrade, I want to reinstall the old PSU for sale, and put the newer one in the next server

Comment: @StringsOnFire you would just do it again. It's completely reversible.